# What is the right way to define child routes in Spartacus?

Tags: angular-routing, spartacus-storefront

I am working in a B2B Spartacus project and we are currently implementing the MyCompany User/Unit management. The Spartacus implementation is a little to complex for our use-case so we are developing a custom solution based on it.

The original implementation features a CMS-Page for users (e.g.: https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:444/powertools-spa/en/USD/organization/users) and then Angular child routes for the user details (e.g.: `/organization/users/7a95e933-364c-4c8d-81cd-4f290df0faf1`)

I tried to replicate the child route implementation following the Spartacus documentation.

1. I created a parent (RightsManagementUser) and child (RightsManagementUserDetails) component.[image]

   ```
   <p>rights-management-user works!</p>
   <a
     class="btn btn-primary"
     [routerLink]="{ 
         cxRoute: 'orgUserDetails', 
         params: { customerId: '9e26d9fb-14eb-4ec6-9697-3fa53302245c' } 
       } | cxUrl"
     >Go to User Details</a
   >
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   ```
2. Following the [Spartacus Documentation](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/route-configuration/#children-routes-nested-routes), I provided a Spartacus and an Angular routing config

   ```
   export const userRoutingConfig: RoutingConfig = {
     routing: {
       routes: {
         orgUser: {
           paths: ['organization/users'],
         },
         orgUserDetails: {
           paths: ['organization/users/:userCode'],
           paramsMapping: {
             userCode: 'customerId',
           },
         },
       },
     },
   };


   RouterModule.forChild([
     {
       path: null,
       component: PageLayoutComponent,
       canActivate: [CmsPageGuard],
       data: { cxRoute: 'orgUser' },
       children: [
         {
           path: null,
           component: RightsManagementUserDetailsComponent,
           data: { cxRoute: 'orgUserDetails' }
         },
       ],
     },
   ]),
   ```
3. I also tried following the documentation for [Adding Angular Child Routes for a Content Page](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/adding-and-customizing-routes/#adding-angular-child-routes-for-a-content-page)
    and added the child route to the cms config.

   ```
   RightsManagementUserComponent: {
     component: RightsManagementUserComponent,
     childRoutes: [
       {
         path: ':userCode',
         component: RightsManagementUserDetailsComponent,
       },
     ],
   },
   ```

This all wasn't enough, when clicking the button, the CMSPageGuard tries to load the CMS page for `/organization/users/7a95e933-364c-4c8d-81cd-4f290df0faf1` instead of activating the child route.

I then tried to go the Angular way and defined the child route without using cxRoute:

```
    children: [
      {
        path: ':userCode',
        component: PflRightsManagementUserDetailsComponent,
      },
    ],
```

At first I was happy, since the child route actually activated:

[image]

But then I realized that when I do a browser refresh Spartacus again tries to access the CMS-Page instead of activating the route.

Can someone please help me out and point me to the right way to use child routes in Spartacus?

Comment: I am analyzing your issue. [There](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus-docs/pull/979/files?short_path=195dfcf#diff-195dfcfca5fd17936219ac663b935725f5f1978361fe7c801cb09c6bb8b1d24f) is prepared documentation for my company, but not merged yet. Please see in the meantime

Comment: Are you able to put that part of implementation on stackblitz? Are you going to use split view? I don't exactly understand what you want to exchange. Maybe please provide some draw of structure of components with routes.

Comment: Hey Armin, did you ever figure out how to solve it? I also tried to follow the official documentation, but always land on the 404 page because the router tries to load a combination of parent and child route as cms page..

Comment: Hey everyone! I worked around the issue by just using two separate CMS- pages and didn't have time to follow up on this thread. What I wanted to achieve is, to use angular child routes in one CMS-Component (e.g. multiple steps in a workflow). So basically what is described here: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/route-configuration/#children-routes-nested-routes. I haven't tried if that works now in the newer versions. Maybe @user2477219 can give some insight there.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use split view, you can define your route in this way [#customizing-routes](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/b2b-commerce-organization/#customizing-routes), then clone whole cms configuration for organization feature and personalize childs [#customizing-cms-components](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/b2b-commerce-organization/#customizing-cms-components).

It could looks like:

```
const yourConfig = { ...userCmsConfig.cmsComponents.ManageUsersListComponent };
(yourConfig.childRoutes as CmsComponentChildRoutesConfig).children[1].component = RightsManagementUserDetailsComponent;
```

and include in your module

```
  imports: [
   // ...
   B2bStorefrontModule.withConfig({
      // ...
      cmsComponents: {
        ManageUsersListComponent: yourConfig,
      },
    },
   // ...
```